# Rails server gives error when I load localhost:3000 and it's not the rack version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Before you mark this as a duplicate, know that the difference between this question and the other questions is there are no errors in the console or logs for me!

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.0.alpha application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-10-25 17:32:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-10-25 17:32:22] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2015-10-25 17:32:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=33823 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-25 17:32:35 -040
```

Produces a 500 internal server error: "We're sorry but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

I've tried:

- changing the rack version to 1.6.2 (ruby requires >2.0)
- using a different port
- binding the rails server to localhost
- hitting 127.0.0.1:3000, 0.0.0.1:3000, etc

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add more info about the error you are getting? What's the error message?

Comment: are you using a browser in the same computer as the rails server is?

Comment: is there anything written in the `\log\developmen.log` file? (please stop your app, delete this file and start it)

Comment: @TheFabio `development.log` just writes `Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-10-25 19:23:44 -0400` for each attempt to hit localhost:3000